# should I do a correlation?

Tags: correlation

I don't know anything about statistics, but I am trying my best to learn :) I have two sets of data of a city. First one is the median of the personal net monthly income per district, and the second one is the per capita green space per district. I wanna know if the income will predict the amount of green space, so I'm not sure if what I need to use here is a correlation test? Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do a correlation. If it is positive, then your data suggests a positive relation between income and green space at the district level within your city. If it is negative, then as one goes up, the other goes down. The larger the correlation in either direction, the stronger the relationship in that direction.

I would even add that before you do a correlation, use some software, maybe excel to produce a plot of district income on the x-axis and green space on the y. If the plot is intelligible, and you can make sense of it, this may be of more benefit to you than any correlation value you compute. If you can't make sense of it, then you should be cautious interpreting the correlation in the manner I have up top. If the trend you find deviates markedly from a straight line, then the correlation you calculate will struggle to capture the relationship you can see in the plot, and the plot is many times better.

This is as far as I'd advise you go. It is not a good idea to attempt to do statistics when one does not "know anything about statistics". Stay away from *p*-values, they may not even be relevant to you. Plot and if you can understand the trend from the plot, interpret the result of the correlation in a manner similar to what I've written.

My response assumes you're not going to suddenly learn statistics.

Answer (score 0):

Equivalently you can run a [simple regression](http://www.statmethods.net/stats/regression.html) of $y = \alpha + \beta x + u$, where $y$ is per capita green space and $x$ is median income. Then test whether $\beta$ is significantly different from zero. If so, income can (partially) explain the distribution of green space.

Comment: While true, this is likely beyond this particular individual.